# Read xls row by row with formatting

Tags: c#, xls

I want to read data from my excel and write it to a PDF.

I want to keep the excel data formatting as it is. it might contain tables( cells with borders like table).

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: for writing as PDF, i am using itextsharp. Can I use openxml to read it.

Comment: Yes you may use openxml, but I would suggest [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/801032/ExcelDLL.zip). You can read about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-of)

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499562/excel-to-pdf-c-sharp-library) post could be very helpful